# Dynamic title and description in the Nunjucks template engine

Tags: json, nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

I'm trying to understand the language of [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) templates.

To generate HTML I use Gulp + plugin gulp-nunjucks-render.

Faced a problem: I can not understand how to implement the generation of meta tags title and description.

**Project file structure:**

```
project
 |
 | -> dist > index.html (compiled)
 |           page1.html (compiled)
 |           page2.html (compiled)
 |
 |
 | -> src 
        |-> pages -> index.njk (home page)        
        |            page1.njk (page 1)      
        |            page2.njk (page 2)            
        |
        |-> templates
        |            |-> layout.njk
        |            |
        |            |-> parts -> header.njk
        |                         footer.njk
        |
        |-> styles -> style.css
        |             style.min.css
        |
        |-> data.json
```

**layout.njk**

```
<!-- layout.njk -->

<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>{{ title }}</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  </head>
  <body class="page">
      {% block header %}{% endblock %}
      {% block main %}{% endblock %}
      {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Which I connect to each page as follows:

```
{% extends "layout.njk" %}
```

**index.njk**

```
{% extends "layout.njk" %}

{% block header %} {% include "parts/header.njk" %} {% endblock %}
{% block main %}
    <main class="main">
    <!-- content -->
    </main>
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %} {% include "parts/footer.njk" %} {% endblock %}
```

**page1.njk**

```
{% extends "layout.njk" %}

{% block header %} {% include "parts/header.njk" %} {% endblock %}
{% block main %}
    <main class="main">
    <!-- content page1 -->
    </main>
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %} {% include "parts/footer.njk" %} {% endblock %}
```

**page2.njk**

```
{% extends "layout.njk" %}

{% block header %} {% include "parts/header.njk" %} {% endblock %}
{% block main %}
    <main class="main">
    <!-- content page1 -->
    </main>
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %} {% include "parts/footer.njk" %} {% endblock %}
```

I couldn't find any examples of title output in the [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html), so the most an interesting way to I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439991/nunjucks-dynamic-page-template).

For example, get the title and description from a file .JSON

**data.json**

```
"pages": [
    {
        title: "Hompage"
        description: "This is the home page"
    },
    {
        title: "Page1"
        description: "This is page 1"
    }
    {
        title: "Page2"
        description: "This is page 2"
    }
]
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp           = require('gulp');
const nunjucksRender = require('gulp-nunjucks-render');
const data           = require('gulp-data');

gulp.task('nunjucks', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/pages/**/*.njk')
  .pipe(data(function() {
    return require('./src/data.json')
  }))
  .pipe(nunjucksRender({
    path: ['src/templates']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('docs'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(cb) {
    gulp.parallel(
        'nunjucks',
    )(cb);
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.njk', gulp.series('nunjucks'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch'));
```

I don't know how to extract data from json. Please advise a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you `extends` `layout.njk` in your pages, you could set the `title` and the `description` variables at the top of the document like so:

```js
{% set title = myTitle %}
{% set description = myDescriptionHere %}
```

Then you do that for every pages (`index.njk`, `page1.njk`, `page2.njk`, etc.)

Alternatively, you could define your variables in `nunjucksRender` in the `gulpfile.js` as so:

```js
.pipe(nunjucksRender({
    path: ["yourPath"],
    title: "yourTitle",
    description: "yourDescriptionHere"
}))
// Rest of the code...
```

I didn't test it, I just deduce that from de documentation and great articles:
[Killer features of Nunjucks](https://css-tricks.com/killer-features-of-nunjucks/)
and
[Building a static website with components using Nunjucks](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/03/static-site-with-nunjucks/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are hoping to pass the data from `data.json` file

**Step 1**: you need to use someway to specify the page name in the data file itself.

Eg: data.json

```
{
    "pages": {
        "home": {
            "title": "Hompage",
            "description": "This is the home page"
        },
        "page1": {
            "title": "Page1",
            "description": "This is page 1"
        },
        "page2": {
            "title": "Page2",
            "description": "This is page 2"
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: You have to set the page name as a variable in the nunjucks page.

Eg: index.njk

```
{% set pageName = 'home' %}
{% extends "layout.njk" %}

{% block header %} {% include "parts/header.njk" %} {% endblock %}
{% block main %}
    <main class="main">
    <!-- content -->
    </main>
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %} {% include "parts/footer.njk" %} {% endblock %}
```

**Step 3**: Use the `pageName` variable in any nunjucks page, layout or partial to get the specific data for a specific page.

Eg: layout.njk

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>{{ pages[pageName].title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  </head>
  <body class="page">
    {% block header %}{% endblock %}
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
    {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I didn't compile and test this code. So make sure all *variables and code syntax* are correct if you are directly copying this code. The logic must work based on the [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `extends`, you should redefine block to override it

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

var html = `
{% extends "layout.njk" %}

{% block header %}
    {{pages[1].title}}
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    {{pages[1].description}}
{% endblock %}
`

var data = {
    pages: [
    {
        title: "Hompage",
        description: "This is the home page"
    },
    {
        title: "Page1",
        description: "This is page 1"
    },
    {
        title: "Page2",
        description: "This is page 2"
    }]
}

res = nunjucks.renderString(html, data);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I don't fully understand. Inserted the code you suggested into gulpfile.js and got a syntax error. I slightly corrected my question, pointed to the file structure and some more details. I would be very grateful if you explain in more detail how to organize everything for work.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want exactly: why `page1.njk` = `page2.njk`? Where is `nunjucks` use your data? Also I don't know `gulp` and so I don't know how it iterate over pages.

Comment: 'page1' and 'page2' have a common header and footer, only the main content is different. Nunjucks takes data from external data.json (return require('./src/data.json')). If you find it difficult to answer, it does not matter. You have already given a hint, I'll try to figure it out somehow.